# Why is C# console application not returning result on LINQ Select with data

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm writing a rather complicated database scanning utility using a console application, but for some reason I'm running into the most basic of problems when I attempt to do a simple LINQ SELECT on a database table with data.

When the database table has no data, the query returns control to the console application.
When the table has data, SQL server shows "SUSPENDED" and "ASYNC_NETWORK_IO".

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Program.cs looks as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataModels dm = new DataModels();
        List<string> lsReturn = dm.ReturnDataFromTableX();
    }
}
```

DataModels.cs looks as follows:

```
class DataModels
{
    public List<string> ReturnDataFromTableX()
    {
        return _DataEntities.<TABLE_NAME>.Select(x => x.<COLUMN_NAME>).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lync. Did you mean LINQ?

Comment: Please provide the complete exception that you are getting, including message and stack trace

Comment: My apologies.  Yes, I'm referring to LINQ.  I correctly referenced LINQ in the text of the question, but selected the wrong tag.

Comment: No exception is received.  The call to the database is made and I receive no return.  The "SUSPENDED" and "ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" is observed in SSMS - Activity Monitor.

Comment: How many rows of data?  ASYNC_NETWORK_IO usually happens when the DBMS is waiting for the client to receive the data.    See [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57402/is-async-network-io-wait-type-anything-to-worry-about) for more info.

Comment: Less than 30,000 rows of data are being selected.  The data being selected is XML data, but I would think the return would be much sooner....investigating whether I just need to be more patient.

Comment: 30,000 rows of XML sounds like a *considerable* amount of data being transferred on the wire.  Yeah, I think that's your problem.

Comment: Amy is correct.  I was expecting a much quicker return and assumed my code was the problem, but I wasn't giving the system enough time to return the data back to the application.  That's the good news.  Bad news is that I have tables with over 500,000 records and they are causing an OutofMemory exception to be thrown.

Comment: Than use paging with `Take` and `Skip` functions, and scan DB by blocks. Return IEnumerable instead of List and use `yield return` with release of memory

Comment: I had considered using IEnumerble instead of List before.  I've made this change, but continue to experience Memory Issues.  I'm investigating the use of Take, Skip, and Yield further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can try

```
class DataModels
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ReturnDataFromTableX()
    {
        return _DataEntities.<TABLE_NAME>.Select(x => x.<COLUMN_NAME>);
    }
}
```

it will track the returned row in the table and if your processing is not really long, than it should be already enough
or alternatively ready block by block in that case connection will be opened to read portion of data each time it is really required:

```
var page = 0;
var step = 10;
var block = _DataEntities.<TABLE_NAME>.Skip(page * step).Take(step).Select(x => x.<COLUMN_NAME>).ToList();
while (block.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in block)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
    page++;
    block = _DataEntities.<TABLE_NAME>.Skip(page * step).Take(step).Select(x => x.<COLUMN_NAME>).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I attempted this implementation, but line 3 (first block statement) yielded a NotSupportedException [The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities.  The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'].

Comment: Add `.OrderBy(x => x.<COLUMN_NAME>)` before skip to each call

Comment: Yes, I had already modified the block statement as follows:
    _DataEntities.<TABLE_NAME>.OrderBy(x => x.DATE_RECEIVED).Skip(page * step).Take(step).Select(x => x.<COLUMN_NAME>).ToList()

I'm testing now.

Comment: If I modified the select to return multiple values, what would be the best way to "yield return" both values into an IEnumerable.
public class DataToReturn

Comment: Shold works, it doesn't actually matters what are you returning with yield, the point is to not download all and release resources one by one

Comment: I modified the original SELECT to return 4 columns instead of the original 1.  That is working just fine.  I've also implemented the suggested block/yield with skip/take.  The good news is that I'm not getting a memory error.  The bad news is that testing seems to reveal that the implementation is not preventing the SELECT from re-selecting the same rows...basically, I'm selecting more rows than exist in the table and they are repeating themselves....research continues.

Comment: Sounds strange, Try to choose Unique identifier as sorting column.

Comment: ASpirin - thanks so much for your help.  I figured out what was causing the duplication of processing and changed my ORDER BY column (Date Received wasn't unique and was causing different ordering).  I have marked this suggestion as the answer.  Much appreciated!  [Funny, I just read your suggestion on column...great minds think alike!].